# Is it possible to drop a triangle from being rendered using vertex shaders?

Tags: shader, vertex-shader

In a pixel shader you can discard a pixel but I would imagine even a fast-fail shader called for every pixel takes a non-trivial time? Is there any way a vertex shader can discard an entire triangle... I am fairly sure a VS *can't* access the primitive but are there any tricks  by which we can get the same result?

Talking SM 3.0 here - for completeness discussion on newer versions is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometry shader can do that trivially as you probably know, but no such thing in SM3.

It's harsh for the vertex shader to identify a triangle as such, since all the vertex shader sees is the individual vertices. But... in principle it's possible.

If you set the w coordinate to zero, a point will be projected to infinity. Set the w coordinates of all points to zero, and the entire triangle is at infinity, so it won't be rendered.

Alternatively, you could probably set gl_ClipDistance to zero or a value below zero (never really used those, but I guess this should work). That would mark the vertex as "behind" a clipping plane. If all three vertices are behind a clipping plane, the triangle is not visible.

You would need a way to identify the vertices that belong to the triangle that you want to discard, however... and that will not be easy unless you have a very special situation (such as for example knowing that you want to discard all triangles in some given bounding box, or all triangles in which the vertex attribute #5 is zero, or whatever).

Comment: Interesting ideas. My case is basically a per-tri culling based on a  custom slice-plane (passed in shaders params). We do per-pixel tests but if we could drop entire polys that would be great. The problem is I guess, from _a_ vertex, how to know if the other 2 are also on the 'wrong' side. Really I want to set some property on the vertex which has no effect unless _all 3_ vertices have it set.

Comment: But, but... is that not simply an user clip plane then? A single custom slice-plane should be supported pretty much on every hardware (I think even 5-6 years ago cards used to support 4 or so extra planes). Or, it could probably even be done with the "oblique near plane" hack.

Comment: @dm.skt Yes it is but on the pixel level (triangles which get sliced get part-drawn). Are you suggesting we add a hardware clip-plane which will cull whole polys, then only those at least partially visible remain for the pixel-shader to process?

Comment: Well what clipping (with a hardware clipplane or against the frustum, likewise) does is: a) nothing if the entire triangle is "in", b) slice through the triangle, introducing a new edge, if some verts are "in" and some are "out", and c) discard the entire triangle if all vertices are "out". So, if I understood your original concern correctly, that would be just what you want.

Comment: @dm.skt I don't recall that hardware clipping planes work on the per-pixel level in D3D9 as you describe. If you've got a link I'm happy to be proved wrong/

Comment: They work per triangle (or polygon), not per pixel. I'm not familiar with the D3D documentation, but since OpenGL runs on the same hardware, see the GL2.1 spec: "If the primitive is a polygon, then it is passed if every one of its edges lies entirely inside the clip volume and either clipped or discarded otherwise. Polygon clipping may cause polygon edges to be clipped, but because polygon connectivity must be maintained, these clipped edges are connected by new edges that lie along the clip volume’s boundary. Thus, clipping may require the introduction of new vertices into a polygon."

Comment: Which is, as you said "discard a triangle entirely", just what you want! :-)